# How to access mysql table data of different machine every hour?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, remote-connection

I want to access data from a mysql table which is on different database on different machine. Both the machines are connected to same network. I tried access using

```
select * from [10.1.18.244].dbname.dbo.tablename;
```

But its giving me syntax error and also I don't know what exactly is dbo and how to find it out?

And, also I found that it can be done using linked server, but I don'tknow how to do this?

Actually I want this in query form only because I want to apply this in Stored Procedure like

```
DELIMITER //
create definer = 'root'@'10.1.18.244' procedure user_cnt()
sql security invoker
begin 
select * from dbname.tablename;
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

Any method which will be useful for querying data in events/views/procedures please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
?>`

Localhost using in the Server name or server ip.

and also mysql is differ from sql query.

Comment: Hey, I want it in mysql query form only

Comment: Can U refer this Tutorial once it is use full to us https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-tutorial